# How can I iterate through different, consecutive parts of a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm looking to iterate through different parts of the second list in consecutive order. The output of my first code block is like this:

```
[12, 6, 6, 3, 12, 5]

[]

[6, 9, 4, 1, 13, 14]

[]

[13, 4, 5, 17, 20, 0]

[]

[4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 13, 6, 2, 4]
```

Using this, I want to iterate through each list, using each number to find the majority number for that set of elements in the second list. My second list looks like this:

```
[21, 21, 24, 25, 26, 21, 21, 21, 21, 23, 24, 63, 68, 98, 98, 98...]
```

I want to use the corresponding number in the list from the first output (i.e., 12 for the first iteration) and find the majority number that exists for the first 12 elements in the list. Then, I want to go to the next element (5) and find the majority number in the NEXT five elements in the list, continuing that until it reaches the end of the first list. After this, I want to go to the third list from the first code block (since even number lists will be blank) and go through each element in that, finding the set of the next few numbers in my second list. Output should be like the following:
(assuming that each number is the majority from the set of elements in the first code block output list -- and there's 5 elements because there were 5 elements in the first list of the code block as well).

```
21 21 32 34 35

21 45 45 65 66
```

I tried using this approach:

```
start = 0
for i in range(len(lis)):
  for i in range(start, len(l)):
```

But, I don't know how to iterate through the list at different start and end indices.

Comment: Start by not using two `i`s. Thats bad for your loops.

Comment: Also your start variable is not updated.

Comment: But I can't figure out how to iterate through different sections of the list.